# Searchbar inside navbar calls an HTTP request, want returned data to populate in another component

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building a site that allows one to search for a beer and it returns data about that beer.  The user clicks the search button, and it runs the http request I have setup on a service.  All displays fine.  But what I am trying to do is move my search form from the displaying component, to be inside the navbar.  How do I link the search form on the navbar to the viewing component?

here is the home.component where the search form currently sits(clicking search runs the "searchBeer" function below passing the beer name being searched for:

```
@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: './home.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private beerSearchService:BeerSearchService) { }
beerName:string;
beers:{};
selectedBeer: {};

searchBeer(beerName){
  this.beers=null;
  this.beerSearchService.searchBeer(beerName)
  .subscribe(data => console.log(this.beers=data));
  this.selectedBeer=null;
 }

 onSelect(beer): void {
 this.selectedBeer = beer;
 console.log(beer);
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }
}
```

EDIT... Had wrong service before.....
beer-search.service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BeerSearchService{

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

searchBeer(name){

let data= {
  query: `{beerSearch(query:"`+name+`"){items{id, name, style {description}, description, overallScore,
   imageUrl, abv, brewer {name, facebook, web}}}}`,
  variables:"{}",
  operationName:null
}

return this.http.post('https://api.r8.beer/v1/api/graphql/', data, {
  headers:{
     'x-api-key': '<API-KEY>'}
    });
 }
}
```

If I move the search bar to the navbar component, how do I call this searchBeer function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store the results of API call to `BehaviorSubject` in the service, from `navbar` call the method to get beers from API and in component instead of subscribing to API result, subscribe to `Observable` (from `BehaviorSubject` of BeerS - your data):

`BeerSearchService`

```
export class BeerSearchService {

  private _beers = new BehaviorSubject<Beer[]>(null);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  searchBeer(beerSearch?: string) {
    // do something with beerSearch parameter
    let data = {
      query: `  {topBeers{items{id, name, style {description}, description, 
       overallScore, imageUrl, abv, brewer {name, facebook, web}}}}`,
      variables:"{}",
      operationName:null
    };

    this.http.post('https://api.r8.beer/v1/api/graphql/', data, {
      headers: {'x-api-key': '<api-key>'}
      }).subscribe(data => {
        this._beers.next(data);
      });
  }

  get beers$() {
    return this._beers.asObservable();
  }
}
```

`navbar.ts`

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(private beerSearchService: BeerSearchService) {}

   searchBeer(beerName) {
     this.beerSearchService.searchBeer(beerName);
   }
}
```

`Component.ts`

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnDestroy {
  beers:{};
  sub: Subscription;

  constructor(private beerSearchService: BeerSearchService) {
    this.sub = this.beerSearchService.beers$.subscribe(beers => {
     this.beers = beers;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm new to angular and thought I was doing ok, but I realize there is soooo much more to learn....  I never saw these procedures such as BehaviourSubject.  I need to learn a lot more, especially the RXJS stuff.  Gonna search for that subject on youtube.

So on the component.ts, I no longer need the OnInit  now that I'm using the OnDestroy??

Comment: Don't worry, you are doing OK, for a start your question was not downvoted :) If you are serious about Angular, definitely take a look at Rxjs (Observables, Subjects) and operators there like _filter_, _switchMap_. It might take a while to get used to it but once you do it helps a lot. Take a look at `async` pipe in Angular as well. You might need `ngOnInit` for other stuff but not for the wiring of this. Just note that you should always unsubscribe from observables to avoid memory leaks, which is what I did in `ngOnDestroy`. Happy coding.